# jQuery $('body').on('click', '.element') not working properly

Tags: jquery

jQuery documentation clearly states that when providing an `.element`, it will monitor for click events on that selector, but in my case it triggers all `.on('click')` codes I have and I'm not sure why. I'm using latest jQuery for the moment, v3.7.1 and the elements are dynamically created when receiving data from API.

Example code:

```
$(function() {
  let $body = $('body'),
    $element1 = $('.element1'),
    $element2 = $('.element2');

  $body.on('click', $element1, function () {
    console.log('element 1');
  });

  $body.on('click', $element2, function () {
    console.log('element 2');
  });
});
```

When I click on either `element 1` or `element 2`, I see in console that both `console.log()` have been triggered.

Why?

Comment: The second argument of `.on()` is not meant to be a jQuery object but rather a CSS selector string. Try `$body.on('click', '.element1', function () {
    console.log('element 1');
  });`.

Comment: Change it to `$element1 = '.element1',`

Comment: @CarstenMassmann Huh, I was 100% sure I used jQuery object in the past and that it worked, not sure why I thought that. Thanks for the tip! You can paste it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of .on() is not meant to be a jQuery object but rather a CSS selector string. Try

```
$body.on('click', '.element1', function () {  
  console.log('element 1');
});
```

instead.

The original expression `$('.element1')` would have evaluated to an "empty" jQuery object if, as OP says, the `.element1` elements are generated dynamically at a later stage.